# Discord Bot using AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, discord

I am trying to build a discord bot and was wonderig if i can use AWS lambda for it. So far i haven't seen someone did it already so was confuse if its possible or not. Specially when lambda's aren't active all the time.

Comment: Probably not? What would trigger your lambda function?  Generally your bot logs in, then receives data from discord representing changes to the state of the servers it has joined (plus private messages, etc.).  An EC2 makes more sense for that model.

Comment: yeah thats what i was thinking that lambda needs to be triggered. the other option is having an ec2 instance but it sounds an over-kill.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/6qeje7/using_lambda_for_discord_bot/ says no. There's no "outgoing" webhook, so discord can't emit something that could trigger a lambda.

Comment: How will you scale it? can ELB work?

Answer (score 6):

ancient question, but this is now possible, since discord starting providing outgoing webhooks a few weeks ago

(shameless self plug) i wrote a bit of a guide [here](https://oozio.medium.com/serverless-discord-bot-55f95f26f743)

Answer (score 3):

This is now possible but following an integration approach rather than the traditional bot approach. This differs as detailed below.

The [slash commands official documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/slash-commands#slash-commands-interactions-and-bot-users) gives us this info:

> Slash Commands and Interactions bring something entirely new to the table: the ability to interact with an application without needing a bot user in the guild.

You are now able to receive interaction events via your preferred URL endpoint such as an AWS Lamba function, Firebase Cloud function, Azure Cloud function, etc.

This official [receiving an interaction](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/slash-commands#receiving-an-interaction) section tells us:

> In your application in the Developer Portal, there is a field on the main page called "Interactions Endpoint URL". If you want to receive Interactions via outgoing webhook, you can set your URL in this field.

It is **important to remember**, though, that the data sent to the endpoint URL for interactions is not the same as running a bot client, in fact they make comment on that [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/slash-commands#:%7E:text=In%20many%20cases,application%20at%20all.):

> In many cases, you may still need a bot user. If you need to receive gateway events, or need to interact with other parts of our API...

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, although We can post messages by AWS Lambda using Webhook, But we can not receive and process messages using AWS Lambda.
This is because discord does not provide message posting events.

Answer (score 1):

here's a minimal implementation in nodejs that will give you an acceptable *Interactions Endpoint URL*:

serverless.yml

```yaml
service: discord
variablesResolutionMode: 20210326

frameworkVersion: '2'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  stage: whatever
  region: us-east-1
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
  iam:
    role:
      name: discord
      # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-paramstore-access.html
      statements:
        -
          Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - 'ssm:DescribeParameters'
          Resource: '*'
        -
          Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - 'ssm:GetParameter'
          Resource:
            - 'arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1::parameter/discord_token'
            - 'arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1::parameter/discord_application_id'
            - 'arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1::parameter/discord_public_key'

functions:
  interactions:
    handler: handler.interactions
    environment:
      DISCORD_TOKEN: ${ssm:/discord_token}
      DISCORD_APPLICATION_ID: ${ssm:/discord_application_id}
      DISCORD_PUBLIC_KEY: ${ssm:/discord_public_key}
    events:
      -
        http: 
          path: interactions
          method: post
          cors: true
```

handler.js

```js
'use strict';

const nacl = require('tweetnacl');

module.exports.interactions = async (event) => {
  const verified = nacl.sign.detached.verify(
    Buffer.from(event.headers['x-signature-timestamp'] + event.body),
    Buffer.from(event.headers['x-signature-ed25519'], 'hex'),
    Buffer.from(process.env.DISCORD_PUBLIC_KEY, 'hex')
  );
  const body = JSON.parse(event.body);
  const response = {
    body: JSON.stringify(
      verified
        ? { type: body.type }
        : { error: 'invalid request signature' },
      null,
      2
    ),
    statusCode: verified
      ? 200
      : 401
  };
  console.log(JSON.stringify({ event, response }, null, 2));
  return response;
};
```